# Form with Method = "POST" doesn't render in Task Module MS Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am building a bot, that would display custom forms in task modules. We are using .Net Core 3.1 and Bot Framework 4.6.

**Issue:**

I am unable to get a custom form to display in Task Module. It's a form with few input elements and with method="POST" attribute. When I remove "method" attribute the task module displays custom form correctly. I just want to post input field values to the ViewModel.

**When I run the same page with method="post" in browser, I am able to render the page and forward the data to other pages**

**With Method="Post":**

.cshtml page with

[image]

Task Module:

[image]

**Without method="POST" :**

[image]

Task Module:

without method="post"  the page displays correctly, but can't post data to other page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you submit the data in task module form. Your bot will receive `task/submit` invoke request with the data you have filled in form. You can respond the invoke request with other task module if you want this is what we call chaining in task module. Please take a look at [submitting the result of task module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots#submitting-the-result-of-a-task-module)

Comment: can't we navigate from one page to other in Task Module?  Like, If there is one page being displayed in Task Module and on click of button instead of sending the task/submit we can navigate to other page?

Comment: Yes you can Task modules build on the foundation of Microsoft Teams tabs; they are essentially a tab inside a popup window. it will load within the same task module but if you want to perform some action in task module or chaining you should implement the suggestion given above. please take a look at [What are Task Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules)